# Automation tests for AutoCAD and IE working together

Tags: internet-explorer, ui-automation, autocad

I'm interested in writing UI automation tests for an AutoCAD addon which uses IE as part of its UI. It would open IE when user input is required (the addon talks to a web based ECM and uses IE to select documents from the ECM to be downloaded to the users machine and opened in AutoCAD).

The interaction between the addon inside AutoCAD and IE would go like this:

- The user selects "Browse for document" in the addon menu in AutoCAD
- The addon launches IE with the ECM URL
- The user selects a document in the ECM app in IE
- The addon receives a callback from IE and gets the ID of the selected document from the HTTP headers received from the webapp
- The addon closes the browser (the window is just hidden actually)
- The addon downloads the document from the ECM to the user's machine and opens it in AutoCAD

How difficult would it be to automate a scenario like this and what UI automation tool would you use?

It may be possible to use a combination of a UI automation tool for the browser and scripting for AutoCAD, but it looks like it would be easier to do this with a UI automation tool if it allowed this kind of "cross-platform" automation.

Comment: What kinda of Enterprise Content Management System are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you run AutoCAD on Windows you may want to look at [RIATest](http://www.cogitek.com/riatest.html). You should be able to automate AutoCAD using Windows UI Automation and IE as a web application. RIATest supports both of these automation scenarios.

Disclosure: I am a RIATest team member.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. In particular, the part regarding situations where the bulk of your posts seem promotional in nature.